# Environment changes made using "start" are not visible later in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch that is like this

```
@echo off

SET workspace="C:\yii2"

SET deploy_directory="C:\deployment"
SET source_file="C:\deployment\yii2"
SET destination_file="C:\deployment\deployment.zip"

cd "%source_file%"    

start /wait update composer

start /wait xcopy "%workspace%" "%source_file%" /s /h /f

cd "%deploy_directory%"

start /wait zipjs.bat zipItem -source "%source_file%" -destination "%destination_file%" -keep yes -force no

pause
```

The bat file can anywhere be in the system.. So I write something like this.. Currently this is not working .. when it runs and change the directory the command prompt pops out and it does not process the next code.. Is there a silent way to change directory without interruption and will process the next command?

main goal is that to run composer update in the target path. Would appreciate also to explain what's happening here.

Pseudo:

1.) go to workspace path to update composer
2.) Copy workspace to a certain path with my zip bat
3.) change to that directory
4.) Run zipping bat

Edit: Added more steps

Comment: The `start` command has a quirk where the first "quoted argument" is used as a window title, so it may not work as you are expecting. Use `start /wait "" xcopy "%workspace%" "%source_file%" /s /h /f` to force the subsidiary window-title to be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`start` starts a new command window. You just want to change the working directory of the command window that is going to run `update`. So don't use start for the `cd` bit:

```
cd "%source_file%"    
start /wait update composer
```

One reason to use `start` is to run another batch file without terminating the current one. This works because the second batch file is run in a new command shell (and window). Usually, a better option is to use `call`, which runs the second batch file in the current command shell / window but doesn't terminate the current shell. In your case, since `update` is also a batch file, you can use `call`.  So your script now looks like this:

```
cd "%source_file%"    
call update composer
```

Comment: looks like a charm! so start can be omitted just literal running in cmd. Thanks!

Comment: Paul , I had updated my question above.. first was working but when I added the rest steps.. it was running the same. Can you help me out again?

Comment: okay I get your point.. Just to clarify something.. if I omit start.. Will the steps run accordingly what I want? I just dont want to copy if the update is not done yet.. or the confusion happens when I use multiple start , so i have to append /wait?

Comment: `composer update` works now in the correct directory.. Unfortunately it's closing automatically , so therefor it cannot run the remaining scipt..